# Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

Tags: oracle

I Have been getting this error. I don't think I am getting anywhere with it.

I am using `Instant Client 11.2.0.1` and trying to connect to a remote `Oracle 9.2` database. Here is what I have tried:

- Unzipped the Oracle Client in `c:\oracle\` and set the path accordingly
- Added a new environment variable `NLS_LANG` and set it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`
- Re-booted the system after setting the environment variable
- Renamed the `NLS_LANG` value in the `ORACLE_HOME` directory

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12705_resolution.htm)